# Basic compiled LLVM-IR results in segmentation faults

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Trying to familiarize myself with LLVM-IR, but unfortunately I consistently get segfault errors when attempting to compile. I've been testing in particular with this:

```
define void @main() {
entry:
  ret void
}
```

Which from what I know should work and does indeed not result in an error when used with `lli` (I've also tested a 'hello world' I found with similar results, works in `lli` but not when compiled)

I've been using `llc` and `lld` to compile, and I use ubuntu linux (well, bedrock linux but a ubuntu kernal). The versions are consistent (LLVM 10) and I've tested using the gnu linker instead of lld, which has the same result. I've attempted explicitly setting the target triple to no result. I've also tried reinstalling LLVM and related tools, again to no avail. I get the same results on a windows machine through WSL. I have some basic experience with NASM and as I understand it with that you need to make proper syscalls to exit an assembly program gracefully, is perhaps the same true for LLVM-IR? I can only assume I'm doing something terribly wrong, but I can't figure out what it is.

I'm running the commands `llc test.ll --filetype=obj && ld.lld test.o && ./a.out` to compile (as stated above I've tried different params).

Any suggestions on what might be happening here?

Edit:

I've tried to step into it with a debugger, I set a breakpoint at main and interestingly it seg faults before it hits that breakpoint. The result from the debugger is:

```
* thread #1, name = 'a.out', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x1)
    frame #0: 0x0000000000000001
error: memory read failed for 0x0
```

Other than the 'Process launched' and 'Process stopped' bits this is the only output from the debugger.

Comment: You can single-step it. Set a breakpoint in start and go on from there. Btw, main returns int.

Comment: @arnt I stepped through and it gives a seg fault immediately. It tells me it tries to refer to an invalid address at 0x1, resulting in the seg fault.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in start, not main, and use the commands that step single machine instructions. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

can you try using gnu ld, since the error shows `error: memory read failed for 0x0`, i assume the linker is messing with the start address. please provide the output of `objdump -D a.out`